# How does this awk command work?

Tags: awk

The following remarkably terse command will print all of the lines after the first occurrence of a pattern (including the first occurrence):

```
awk '/pattern/,0'
```

Can someone explain how this command works? How does awk parse '/pattern/,0'?

(By the way, I didn't come up with this; it was posted on [compgroups.net](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.awk/print-all-lines-after-first-occurence/235021).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `awk '/foo/,/bar/{print $0}' file` will print every line in the file from the word `foo` until `bar`.

This `/foo/,/bar/` syntax is called a range pattern. If the first regular expression constant `/foo/` is matched the block will be executed until the second regular expression constant `/bar/` is matched. By setting the second regular expression constant to 0 *(i.e. false)* it will never be matched so the block is executed on every line until the end of the file.

In `awk` if you don't specify a `block` of code to executed for a condition then the default block `{print $0}` is executed.

Answer (score 5):

Per the `awk` man page:

> Patterns are arbitrary Boolean combinations (with ! || &&)  of  regular
>    expressions  and relational expressions. ...
>
> A  pattern  may  consist  of two patterns separated by a comma; in this
>    case, the action is performed for all lines from an occurrence  of  the
>    first pattern though an occurrence of the second. ...

Here the first one is `/pattern/` and the second is a literal constant `0`, which is false.  So this starts at the first line that matches, and stops when a line does not exist at all, which only occurs after the file ends.

As another example, compare:

```
jot 10
```

with:

```
jot 10 | awk 'NR==4,NR==6 { printf("line %d: %s\n", NR, $0) }'
```

Comment: No: `/pattern/` is a single-address form so it only matches lines that match the pattern.  The dual-address form triggers on the first match and turns off again on the second match.

Comment: Too late to fix wording of previous comment, it should say "after" the second match.  (Try the above `jot` for example.)